# Django - What is wrong with my view function?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

In this function, the script can't get past the second if statement.

```
def save_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('id')\
        and request.POST.get('id1')\
        and request.POST.get('id2'):
            try:
                print('if2')
                data=Flow()
                data.id = request.POST.get('id')
                data.id1 = request.POST.get('id1')
                data.id2 = request.POST.get('id2')
                data.save()
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
```

My question is pretty simple, why might this be happening?

If I remove the if/and block entirely I get this:

```
ValidationError ['“on” value must be either True or False.']
```

If I remove all of the ands except for one, I have the original problem - where nothing is showing up in my database but no errors are shown either.

URL pattern:

```
    path('io/save_data', views.save_data, name='save_data')
```

Model:

```
class Flow(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    id = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
    id1 = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=False)
    id2 = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 100, decimal_places = 5, default=1)
```

Comment: @FabriceJaouën In which section of the code? The first? | if request.POST['id']: | or second? | data.id = request.POST['id'] |

Comment: Can you post your template also?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a `try & except` ? why not using an else statement at the end ?

also why this :

```
if request.POST.get('id')\
    and request.POST.get('id1')\
    and request.POST.get('id2'):
```

would love to see more code :)

Comment: I wish I had a good reason, but that's basically just how I've built views functions to save form inputs to a database in the past. The try & except was just me trying to get it to show an error. I'm updating the post now.

Answer (score 0):

As I haven't seen your HTML template, I will add this point for good measure. Double check that the fields are named as you call them in your view.

You should also look into using Django-forms for better validation and checking within your codebase. Forms are very useful. See the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/).

As for your code, after checking out the above two points, try this.

```
def save_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        id = request.POST.get('id')
        id1 = request.POST.get('id1')
        id2 = request.POST.get('id2')
        Flow.objects.create(id=id, id1=id1, id2=id2)
```

Try this and let me know if anything is created.

Comment: I have been messing around with this for hours, but I keep getting an unexpected keyword argument for one of the form fields. I think the problem could be due to me trying to use the author and date/time without mentioning them in my views. I've built a form with forms.ModelForm but haven't been able to implement it.

Comment: I cannot help much further until you update with your HTML template to see the form you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to this:

data.id = True if request.POST.get('id') == “True” else False

data.id1 = True if request.POST.get('id1') == “True” else False

Comment: Please upload code for template file and forms.py.